# How to test whether a node contains particular string or character as its text value?

Tags: c#

How to test whether a node contains particular string or character using C# code.

example:

```
<abc>
  <foo>data testing</foo>
  <foo>test data</foo>
  <bar>data value</bar>
</abc>
```

Now I need to test the particular node value has the string "testing" ?

The output would be "foo[1]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also that into an XPath document and then use a query:

```
var xPathDocument = new XPathDocument("myfile.xml");
var query = XPathExpression.Compile(@"/abc/foo[contains(text(),""testing"")]");

var navigator = xpathDocument.CreateNavigator();
var iterator = navigator.Select(query);

while(iterator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(iterator.Current.Name);    
    Console.WriteLine(iterator.Current.Value);    
}
```

Comment: How to display the name and value of the node with your code? using property Name and Value gives error.

Comment: @beginner: I updated my answer to loop through the results and print out the name and value of each.

Answer (score 2):

This will determine if any elements (not just foo) contain the desired value and will print the element's name and it's entire value. You didn't specify what the exact result should be, but this should get you started. If loading from a file use `XElement.Load(filename)`.

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(@"<abc>
  <foo>data testing</foo>
  <foo>test data</foo>
  <bar>data value</bar>
</abc>");

// or to load from a file use this
// var xml = XElement.Load("sample.xml");

var query = xml.Elements().Where(e => e.Value.Contains("testing"));
if (query.Any())
{
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Name, item.Value);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value not found!");
}
```

Comment: how to specify the path instead of writing the xml tags inside XElement.Parse. I need to load an external file with name "sample.xml"

Comment: @beginner I updated the code to show this (commented below the xml). I had mentioned in my post that you could use `XElement.Load("sample.xml")` or you may also use `XDocument.Load("sample.xml")` but if you use an `XDocument` you'll need to use `xml.Root.Elements(...)` (notice the `Root` property).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to Xml

```
string someXml = @"<abc>
                  <foo>data testing</foo>
                  <foo>test data</foo>
                </abc>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(someXml);

bool containTesting = doc
    .Descendants("abc")
    .Descendants("foo")
    .Where(i => i.Value.Contains("testing"))
    .Count() >= 1;
```